# Standard Deviation on marks of students

Tags: probability

Consider three students in a class, and their marks in exam was $40,50,60$ and $70.$ What is the standard deviation of the data set?

---

We know,

$Var(X)=E(X^{2})-(E(X))^{2}$

And   $s.d.=\sqrt{Var(X)}$

Another formula from wiki, formula for $s.d.=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left ( x_{i}-\bar{x} \right )^{2}}$

---

But from the answer given with  formula,

$Var(X)=\frac{\sum x^{2}}{N}-\left ( \frac{\sum x}{N} \right )^{2}$

So, s.d.=$\sqrt{(40+50+60+70)/4-(1600+2500+3600+4900)/16}=11.18$

Now, which formula should be correct and what should be answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that
$$
\text{Var}{X} = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]  = \mathbb{E}[X^2]- \mathbb{E}[X]^2
$$
and therefore the two ways of calculating the variance always give the same answer. You always have to calculate the average (=expected value) first. In this case, it's
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{40+50+60+70}{4} = 55
$$
Now you can either calulate $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]$ or $\mathbb{E}[X^2]- \mathbb{E}[X]^2$. I'll show how to calculate both:
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2] = \frac{1}{4}\left[ (40-55)^2 + (50-55)^2 + (60-55)^2 + (70-55)^2 \right] = 125
$$
This is considered the standard way of calculating the variance, because you don't need to calculate a second auxiliary variable ($\mathbb{E}[X^2]$). As for the second way, we need the term $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{40^2 + 50^2 + 60^2 +70^2}{4} = 3150
$$
and therefore, the second way of calculating the variance is
$$
\text{Var}{X}   = \mathbb{E}[X^2]- \mathbb{E}[X]^2
= 3150 - 55^2 = 125
$$
And in the end, standard deviation is the square root of $125$.

Comment: So, formula of wiki is not correct? It told divide by N-1??

Comment: The denominator is $N-1$ if you're estimating the standard deviation of a population (a large number of data points) but you only have access to a sample (a small number of data points). So it's important to distinguish **population** standard deviation from **sample** standard deviation.

Answer (score 2):

The formula with $N$ is known to be *biased*, which means that its expectation is not the variance of the population.

[This is because the variance should be computed around the expectation of the population, which is unknow and which you estimate as the arithmetic mean, and this reduces the estimated variance a little.

$$\sum(x-\overline x)^2<\sum(x-\mu)^2$$

and

$$\frac1NE(x-\overline x)^2<\sigma^2.$$
]

The unbiased variance is with $N-1$,

$$\frac{125}3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, both formulas are true. The first one directly follow the definition: the standard deviation is a measure of the dispersion of the values of a statistical sample. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values).

Now, if $X$ is a *discrete* random variable which values are $x_i$ and if they all have the same probability $\frac{1}{n}$, we also have
\begin{align}
\sigma &= \sqrt {\mathbb{E} [(X-\mathbb{E} [X] )^{2}]}\\ &=\sqrt {\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mathbb{E}[X] )^{2}}\\ &= \sqrt {\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n})^{2}}\\ &= \sqrt {\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}
\end{align}
For more details (for example about why you have a $\frac{1}{n-1}$ in your formula and not a $\frac{1}{n}$) see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation).