# Variance of a Fair Coin

Tags: probability

Consider Vamshi decides to toss a fair coin repeatedly until he gets a tail. He makes atmost $4$ tosses.The value of variance $T$ is ($T$ denoted number of tosses) ______

---

I tried like this [Standard Deviation on marks of students](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301280/standard-deviation-on-marks-of-students)

$x-----1 ----- 2 ------3-----4$

$P(x)----\frac{1}{2}-----\frac{1}{4}------\frac{1}{8}----\frac{1}{16}$

Mean is $\frac{1}{4}\left ( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{3}} +\frac{1}{2^{4}}\right )=\frac{15}{64}$

So, variance will be,

$\frac{1}{4}\left [ \left ( \frac{15}{64}-\frac{1}{2} \right )^{2}+\left ( \frac{15}{64}-\frac{1}{4} \right )^{2}+\left ( \frac{15}{64}-\frac{1}{8} \right )^{2} +\left ( \frac{15}{64}-\frac{1}{16} \right )^{2}\right ]=$$\frac{460}{16384}$

---

But answer given like this

$E\left ( X^{2} \right )=1^{2}\times \frac{1}{2}+2^{2}\times \frac{1}{4}+3^{2}\times \frac{1}{8}+4^{2}\times \frac{1}{16}$

$E\left ( X \right )=1\times \frac{1}{2}+2\times \frac{1}{4}+3\times \frac{1}{8}+4\times \frac{1}{16}$

$V\left ( X \right )=E\left ( X^{2} \right )-\left ( E\left ( X \right ) \right )^{2}$$=\frac{252}{256}$

---

Why my approach is giving incorrect result??

Comment: What does it mean that he makes "almost" four tosses?  Do you mean "no more than four tosses"?

Comment: Almost 4 tosses, presumably is 3 tosses?

Comment: Sorry it is 'atmost'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X=4)=1-P(X\le3)=\frac18\ne\frac1{16}$$ It is clear that one of the probabilities must be wrong as you currently don't have $\sum_{\forall x} P(X=x)=1$.

Comment: That word should be 'atmost', plz edit ur ans now.

Comment: @Srestha I knew that you intended to write at most before the edit. My answer reflects this.

Comment: So, u mean question is incorrect, right??

Comment: Yes, in both the question and your supplied answer you have used the wrong probability for $4$ throws.

Comment: ok I understood. Mean shouldn't be divide by $4.$ rather it should use formula $xP(X)$ . right?? So, their given answer at least correct by method, though their question is wrong. right??

Comment: Yes the method in the given answer is correct although one of the probabilities is wrong. We use the following formulae for questions such as this $$E(f(X))=\sum_{\forall x}(f(x)\times P(X=x))$$$$\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your question and the supposed "correct" answer.

1. You have not defined what "$T$" is.
2. The probabilities do not add to unity (which makes the supposedly "correct" answer incorrect).
3. Your calculation of the mean and variance (using your approach) is incorrect.

If we solve Problem 1 and define $T$ as the number of tosses made, where we assume that the tosser will never toss more than four times (i.e. if he/she gets four consecutive heads, no more tosses are made), then the probability distribution of the random variable $T$ is given by
$P(T=1)=1/2, P(T=2)=1/4, P(T=3)=1/8, P(T=4)=1-1/2-1/4-1/8=1/8$, where the last probability is calculated as such because if the tosser does not toss it once, twice, or thrice, he/she will necessarily toss it four times since he/she will not exceed tossing it four times as per his/her rule. This solves Problem 2.

Regarding problem 3, the expected value or mean is the probability-weighted (*not equally weighted*) average of the values that the random variable takes.  The variance is the mean of the squared deviations between the values that the random variable takes and its mean. In mathematical terms,for random variable $X$ with probability distribution $P(x)$ for $x\in X$,

$E(X)=\sum_{x\in X} x P(x)$

$Var(X)=E(X-E(X))^2=\sum_{x\in X} (x-E(X))^2 P(x)$

The mean is then given by $E(X)=1*1/2+2*1/4+...$ and variance by $1/2*(1-E(X))^2+1/4*(2-E(X))^2+...$.  The variance can also be calculated using the approach your answer key has using the identity: $Var(X)=E(X-E(X))^2=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$

Comment: yes correct, edited what is $T$.  But what should be correct ans?? My approach is not incorrect. right??

Comment: I have not calculated it, but you should be able to calculate it using the formulas and the probability distribution. You will not get 252/256 since the answer key is incorrect.